# Understanding Textbook Proof: if theory $T$ is $\omega$-consistent, then if $\vdash_T \text{Prv}(\ulcorner A \urcorner)$ then $\vdash_T A$

Tags: logic, metalogic

Prove if theory $T$ is an axiomatizable $\omega$-consistent extension of $\mathbf{Q}$, then if $\vdash_T \text{Prv}(\ulcorner A \urcorner)$ then $\vdash_T A$

This is a textbook proof in Computability and Logic by Boolos et all, page 234.

Typing what the book says:

> For if we had $\vdash_T \text{Prv}_T(\ulcorner A \urcorner)$, or in other words $\vdash_T \exists y \text{Prf}_T(\ulcorner A \urcorner, y)$ but did not have $\vdash_T A$, then for each $b$, $\lnot \text{Prf}_T(\ulcorner A \urcorner, \mathbf{b})$ would be correct and hence provable in $\mathbf{Q}$ and hence in $T$, and we would have an $\omega$-inconsistency in $T$.

The piece I'm struggling with is why $\vdash_T \exists y \text{Prf}_T(\ulcorner A \urcorner, y)$  doesn't directly imply $\vdash_T A$, but rather it is required that some natural number $b$ exist such that $\text{Prf}_T(\ulcorner A \urcorner, \mathbf{b})$.

Other than that, I understand the rest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the axioms of $T$ may not be *true* when interpreted in the actual natural numbers.  If the sentence $\exists y \text{Prf}_T(\ulcorner A \urcorner, y)$ is true when interpreted in the natural numbers, then that does mean that $\vdash_T A$.  But merely having $\vdash_T \exists y \text{Prf}_T(\ulcorner A \urcorner, y)$ does not automatically mean that $\exists y \text{Prf}_T(\ulcorner A \urcorner, y)$ is really true, if you don't assume that the axioms of $T$ are true.

Comment: $\vdash_T A$ means that $A$ is provable from $T$; if the axioms of $T$ are true then $A$ is true. The axioms of $T$ may not be true, in which case you can't use $T$ to prove anything, including $A$, and $A$ isn't necessarily true or not true.

$\vdash_T \exists y \text{Prf}_T(\ulcorner A \urcorner, y)$ means that if the axioms of $T$ are true, then $\exists y \text{Prf}_T(\ulcorner A \urcorner, y)$ is true. $\vdash_T A$ means that if the axioms of $T$ are true, then $A$ is true. I don't see why $\vdash_T \exists y \text{Prf}_T(\ulcorner A \urcorner, y)$ doesn't imply $\vdash_T A$.

Comment: If we assert that $\vdash_T A$ is true, we aren't making any claims about the truth of $A$ when the axioms of $T$ aren't true. We are claiming that if the axioms of $T$ are true, then $A$ must be true as well.

Comment: $\vdash_T A$ *implies* that if the axioms of $T$ are true, then $A$ is true.  It is not *equivalent* to that statement, though, because even if the axioms of $T$ are not true, $A$ may not be provable from $T$.  Just because the axioms of $T$ aren't all true in the actual natural numbers doesn't mean they are *inconsistent*.

Comment: This last comments sounds identical to what I said. You say, "$\vdash_T A$ implies that if the axioms of $T$ are true, then $A$ is true." That sounds identical to what I wrote that "$\vdash_T A$ means that $A$ is provable from $T$; if the axioms of $T$ are true then $A$ is true." Those sentences are logically equivalent. I still don't see why $\vdash_T \exists y \text{Prf}_T(\ulcorner A \urcorner, y)$ doesn't imply $\vdash_T A$.

Comment: You haven't written down any actual argument for why $\vdash_T \exists y \text{Prf}_T(\ulcorner A \urcorner, y)$ would imply $\vdash_T A$, so I don't know what you have in mind.  Write out the argument step by step and I can tell you which step is wrong.

Comment: Studying the definition of Prf, I see that the correct relation is $\vdash_T A$ if and only if $\vdash_{\mathbf{Q}} \exists b \text{Prf}_T(\ulcorner A \urcorner, \mathbf{b})$. The set of theorems true in any axiomatizable theory $T$ are semirecursive and therefore arithmetically defined by corresponding rudimentary formula $\text{Prf}_T$. Arithmetically definable means true in the standard interpretation or true if the axioms of $\mathbf{Q}$ are true, not necessarily the axioms of $T$. Thanks for having patience to help me through this :)